# Ruby on Rails Action Mailer not working: undefined local variable or method ` '

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Has anyone seen this type of error before:

```
Undefined local variable or method `  ' for #<MyMailer:0x0000000c096530>
```

I am attempting to use ActionMailer to just send a basic email, but it keeps failing on the `.deliver` function.

Here is the necessary code:

```
def index
  MyMailer.welcome_email(test).deliver
end
```

Controller code:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout 'mailer' 
  def welcome_email(user)  
    @user=user
    puts "Message Should have sent"
    mail(to: @user, subject: 'test')
  end
end
```

Mailer code:

```
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
end
```

Comment: ActionMailer uses view templates, but you didn't include them. I suspect that's where your problem lies.

Comment: Also, I think you're mixed up a bit. Your `welcome_email` method is in the wrong class, and `ApplicationMailer` is not a controller. And in the `index` method, you left out the declaration of `test`, which is important. Finally, please include the full stack trace, not just the error message.